# How can I put the App Registration client ID in Azure AD token?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET Core API, where I want to use Azure AD authentication.
I have created an App Registration and provided the config below for my API:

```
 "AzureAd": {
    "TenantId": "<tenantid>",
    "ClientId": "api://<clientid>", // tried it with only the guid clientid as well
  },
```

Authentication config (App registration exposed API scope provided):

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
                options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];
            })
```

My problem is, that when I log in to azure AD, the audience in my token will be 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 (Id of AAD Graph API), instead of the client id of the App registration.

I am using swagger to test the authentication:

```
        app.UseSwaggerUi3(config =>
        {
            config.OAuth2Client = new NSwag.AspNetCore.OAuth2ClientSettings
            {
                ClientId = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"],
                ClientSecret = string.Empty,
                UsePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant = true,
                ScopeSeparator = " "
            };
        });
```

swagger document config:

```
services
    .AddOpenApiDocument(c =>
    {
        c.AddSecurity("OAuth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            OpenIdConnectUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
            Scheme = "Bearer",
            Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
            {
                AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                {
                    AuthorizationUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/oauth2/authorize",
                    TokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/oauth2/token",
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "api://<client id>/Api.Read", "api://<client id>/Api.Read" }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: You need to ask for a token for your API in your front-end application. Can you show how you are getting the token.

Comment: You can go to the API app registration, Expose an API, add a scope, and then use that scope when asking for a token.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried it, but it did not work. I have updated the question to show the swagger doc config with the requested scope

Comment: Try using the v2.0 authorization and token URLs, e.g. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Comment: It works! Thanks for your help, that was an easy to miss detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in comments, found working solution:

1. Define a scope for the API app registration in Expose an API page
2. Use the scope in Swagger UI, e.g.: api://client-id/Api.Read
3. Use the v2.0 token and authorization endpoints:

```
AuthorizationUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
TokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/oauth2/v2.0/token",
Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "api://<client id>/Api.Read", "api://<client id>/Api.Read" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims) the client Id of the requester is contained in the `appid` (v1 tokens) or `azp` (v2 tokens) claim. The behaviour you've observed is correct as the audience is the Id of the party expected to verify the token and provide access to the required resource.